# When does Tony Tony Chopper officially join the crew?

Tags: one-piece

When does Tony Tony Chopper officially join the Straw Hat Pirates crew?

Answer (score 6):

Chapter 152 "Full Moon". On the last double page Luffy shouts "Just shut up and come with us!" and Chopper answers "OK". That's the moment when Chopper joined the crew.